# Angular AJAX form validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am attempting to get some kind of basic AJAX form validation working with Angular but having no joy.  I feel like I've tried every example off the web but none work which lead me to wonder if I've missed something else out?  The custom directives never get called, whether I create them manually or copy and paste off the web.

My HTML is set up like so:

```
<div ng-app="licenceApp" ng-controller="licenceController">
    <form name="licenceForm" novalidate>
        <h2>Licence Key</h2>
        Enter a valid licence key:<span>{{licenceForm.$valid}}</span><br /><br />

        <span style="position:relative;">
            <input type="text" name="LicenceKey" ng-model="LicenceKey" style="width:312px; text-align:center;" username-available-validator required />
            <span ng-if="licenceForm.LicenceKey.$pending">
                Checking LicenceKey...
            </span>

            <input type="submit" value="Apply Key" class="linkbutton" id="applyLicenceKey" style="position: absolute;" ng-disabled="licenceForm.$invalid" />
        </span>
    </form>
```

My javascript code (whose HTTP call will currently fail as its [copied from elsewhere](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2014/09/taming-forms-in-angularjs-1-3.html#asnychronous-validation-via-asyncvalidators) in an attempt to get something working) is

```
angular.module('licenceApp')
    .directive('usernameAvailableValidator', ['$http', function ($http) {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                ngModel.$asyncValidators.usernameAvailable = function (username) {
                    return $http.get('/api/username-exists?u=' + username);
                };
            }
        }
    }])

// Register modules with the licence app
angular.module('licenceApp', [
    'licenceApp.controllers',
    'licenceApp.services',
    'MyAngularFilters'
]);
```

Note that I am looking at Chromes console and see no request being made, I have also tried adding `console.log` to no avail.  What key piece am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you using angular 1.3.0 at least.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive('usernameAvailableValidator', ['$http',
  function($http) {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function($scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        ngModel.$asyncValidators.usernameAvailable = function(username) {
          console.log("validet " +username) 
          $http.get('/api/username-exists?u=' + username);
        };
      }
    }
  }
])
app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.ver = angular.version.full;


});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
      Angular ver:{{ver}}

      <form name="licenceForm" novalidate>
        <h2>Licence Key</h2>
        Enter a valid licence key:<span>{{licenceForm.$valid}}</span>
        <br />
        <br />

        <span style="position:relative;">
            <input type="text" name="LicenceKey" ng-model="LicenceKey" style="width:312px; text-align:center;" username-available-validator required />
            <span ng-if="licenceForm.LicenceKey.$pending">
                Checking LicenceKey...
            </span>

        <input type="submit" value="Apply Key" class="linkbutton" id="applyLicenceKey" style="position: absolute;" ng-disabled="licenceForm.$invalid" />
        </span>
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi.  I am running 1.3.  If I copy your directive into my code it doesnt work! I cant understand what is missing?